# Hive Data model : Table is having more data in one partiion

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, datamodel

My hive table looks like this:

```
create external table abc (
  id string,
  product strring,
  .
  .
  .
  city string
) partitioned by 
(state string) 
location 'path/to/dataFile/in/HDFS';
```

The table is having data of all over the USA and as you can see it is partitioned on state. The sample values in state column are NJ,CA,AZ etc.

The problem is, company is having its most of the business in CA state. So, this table is having 80% of the data in partition state=CA. I need to re-model this as querying to state=CA is taking time as it is having large data.

I am thinking of doing bucketing on the city column but wanted to take views from this forum. Please advise of anyone have any good idea of remodeling it.

Comment: Specificly, what is your most frequent use case of the table ?

Comment: User fetch the data most of the time from CA partition.